# Can you identify this hybrid tea rose?

Tags: identification, flowers

I was given this rose last year as a potted indoor rose. I then put it in the garden in autumn and it has now grown normal size. It has flowers on individual stems and the flowers are creamy with very faint pink 'kisses'. Any ideas?

[image]